# InvalidRequestError when adding data to database with SQLAlchemy and SQL server

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build a many to many relationship with sqlalchemy with pyodbc and SQL Server , and here is my code:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Text
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
courses_students = Table('courses_students',Base.metadata,
                        Column('stu_id',ForeignKey('student.id'),primary_key=True),
                        Column('cour_id',ForeignKey('course.id'),primary_key=True),
                        Column('grade',Integer())
    )

# from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
# Base = declarative_base()

class Student(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'student'

    stu_id = Column('id',Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name',String(10))
    stu_class = Column('class',String(10))
    #courses = relationship('Course',secondary=courses_students,back_populates='students')

    def __init__(self,stu_id,name,stu_class):
        self.stu_id = stu_id
        self.name = name
        self.stu_class = stu_class

    def __repr__(self):
        _str = "Student({_id},{_name},{_class})".format(_id=self.stu_id,_name=self.name,
                                                        _class=self.stu_class)
        return _str

# from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
# Base = declarative_base()

class Course(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'course'

    cour_id = Column('id',Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name',String(20))
    teacher_name = Column('teacher_name',String(10))
    credit = Column('credit',Integer())

    students = relationship('Student',secondary=courses_students,backref='courses')

    def __init__(self,c_id,name,t_name,credit):
        self.cour_id = c_id
        self.name = name
        self.teacher_name = t_name
        self.credit = credit

    def __repr__(self):
        _str = "Course({_id},{_na},{_t_na},{_cre})".format(_id=self.cour_id,_na=self.name,
                                                          _t_na=self.teacher_name,
                                                          _cre=self.credit)
        return _str
```

However, when I tried to add data with `session.add()`, I met the following errors:

> InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'Mapper|Student|student'. Original exception was: When initializing mapper Mapper|Student|student, expression 'course' failed to locate a name ("name 'course' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the  class after both dependent classes have been defined.

Answer (score 0):

That particular error was caused by a typing error and the separate `Base` classes you were creating before you commented them out. I assume that the model definitions were originally in separate files.

`relationship()` expects a mapped class or a string that resolves to such as the first argument, but you passed it `'course'`, which resolves to the `Table` the class is mapped to. It seems that in your example here you have corrected the reference to `'Course'`.

A string argument naming a class passed to `relationship()` is resolved during [mapper compilation time](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/relationships.html#declarative-configuring-relationships) by looking it up from the class registry associated with `Base`. But in your example you have created separate `Base` classes for each of your models and the associative `Table`, so the lookup fails because the classes all reside in separate registries.

The error is raised when using the `Session` for the first time because mappers are configured lazily. As an aside, [`configure_mappers()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.configure_mappers) can be used to configure any pending changes explicitly.

There's another error lurking in your definition of `Course`: instead of `back_populates='courses'` you've used `backref='courses'` and so during configuration the following error is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wtf.py", line 60, in <module>
    configure_mappers()
  File "~/Work/sqlalchemy/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3029, in configure_mappers
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File "~/Work/sqlalchemy/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1828, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File "~/Work/sqlalchemy/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 184, in init
    self.do_init()
  File "~/Work/sqlalchemy/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1659, in do_init
    self._generate_backref()
  File "~/Work/sqlalchemy/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1849, in _generate_backref
    (backref_key, self, m))
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Error creating backref 'courses' on relationship 'Course.students': property of that name exists on mapper 'Mapper|Student|student'
```